# Choosing to spawn different SKSpriteNodes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am making a game and I have objects which fall from the top of the screen to the bottom. I want to spawn choose between the objects and drop one of them. I currently the drop all at the same time.

```
 func ShapePicker() -> SKSpriteNode{
    let shapeArray = [purpleOctagon, coin, greenTriangle, orangeHexagon]

    let MaxValue = self.size.width / 2 - 200
    let MinValue = self.size.width / 3 * 0.95

    let rangeMax = UInt32(MaxValue)
    let rangeMin = UInt32(MinValue)

    purpleOctagon.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(rangeMin) + rangeMax), y: self.size.height)
    self.addChild(purpleOctagon)

    greenTriangle.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(rangeMin) + rangeMax), y: self.size.height)
    self.addChild(greenTriangle)

    coin.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(rangeMin) + rangeMax), y: self.size.height)
    self.addChild(coin)
    return shapeArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(shapeArray.count)))]

}
```

I would like the program to randomly `.addChild` because right now it just puts them on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code implies that you want all of them to be on the screen, and then one randomly drops... So you *do* want to continue to `.addChild`. What you want, is for them to NOT drop all at once.

So, you need to change the `.physicsBody.pinned` to `true` to keep them at the top of the screen.

Then, in your `update()` you can check for how much time has passed, etc, and after a certain # of seconds you can do an `arc4random_uniform` and use that result to change the `.pinned` property of one of the nodes (thus causing that one and that one only to fall).

So, if the coin is 0, triangle is 1, and octagon is 2, then, in your `.update` keep track of the time elapsed and after say 3 seconds, do a random check 0-2, and that check will perform:

```
switch result {
  case 0: // coin
    coin.physicsBody?.pinned = false // makes it drop
  case 1: // triangle
  ...
```

Just make sure that your nodes are in the proper scope so that you can do the logic in `update()`

If I read your Q wrong, and you only want to *spawn and then drop* just one, then you would still need the above switch statement, but instead of changing `physicsBody` you would do `.addChild` instead.

so inside of your func would be more like:

```
// This can be global or inside of your GameScene:
var myGlobalCurrentTime: CFTimeInterval 

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

  myGlobalCurrentTime = myTimerUpdateTime(currentTime)

  func myDropFunc() {

    ... // Initialize your nodes

    let result = myRandomNumber(3)

    switch result {
      case 0:
        coin.position
        = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(rangeMin) + rangeMax),
                  y: self.size.height)
        self.addChild(coin)
      case 1:
        ...
    }
  }

  // Execute the func:
  myDropFunc()
}
```

I'm still a bit confused by your code and question, so please clarify in the comments so I can update this answer if needed.

Comment: Sorry if my question isn't clear enough but I don't need to pin the objects to the screen then drop them; They are created at the slightly above the screen then they drop. The problem is that they drop at the same time as you noted. I want to vary their dropping I already have a timer which spawns them in between 1 - 2.5 seconds but they fall together. I would like to randomly pick a shape from the shapes I have made then drop that single one.

Comment: @uswer1242 the second part of my answer covers that exactly :) Just put your function inside of `.update()`, then do your time calculations.. toss in an `if` statement (to check if 2 seconds have passed) then run your function, with the suggestions I made in the second block.

Comment: oh I see thanks for the help I really appreciate :) one question though would I put the case statements in the time interval method? @Fluidity

Comment: @uswer1242 Well, step back and think about it for a moment.. in update() you need 2 things.. #1 is a way to keep track of time passed (your timer). #2, you need a control block ( if statement ) to check the current time, then do something (drop the sprites) after a certain interval. 

It helps to write / draw / type out a quick plan / layout of what it is you want to do, then you can kind of "fill it in" with your code :)

So no, your actual timer would be separate from the drop function. Your switch / cases _would_ be inside of that control statement (the if check inside of update() )

Comment: @uswer1242 I updated the second code block to demonstrate. It may not be 100% accurate but it gives you the general idea (I'm not at Xcode right now)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help except the thing is when I try to use the      `myGlobalCurrentTime = myTimerUpdate(currentTime)` doesn't work when I import it to swift, I am running swift 2. @Fluidity

Comment: @uswer1242 its called MYfunc because you have to writw it xD  its a simple delta time func just subtract current time from your previoustime var

Comment: Ok I understand that I have to write it lol but I don't know how to use the currentTime API because when I search it NStimer is what is shown @Fluidity

Comment: Oh I found what delta time func. Thanks I didn't know that this was thanks I think got it now :)

Comment: @uswer1242 unfortunately math is an integral part of getting any significant coding done, because logoc is geometry, and geometry is math, and programming is logic :)

Comment: @uswer1242 please dont forget to upvote / accept any answers / comments so other users can use your question as a reference :)

Comment: yes well the thing is that I am new to swift and I come from a java program and it was more data structures, and I wasn't building games so I didn't know what delta time was. I did accept your answer but I don't have enough reputation to upvote just yet. @Fluidity

Comment: @uswer1242 my bad I didn't mean to post that on this thread. I didn't mean to imply anything negative to you. Let me know if you have any more questions, or if you need any reference materials :)

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `addChild` call out of this function, it returns a `SKSpriteNode`, which you can then add.

```
let sprite = ShapePicker()
addChild(sprite)
```

Or, just add the one randomly chosen and return it. You don't need to `addChild` nodes that you're not planning on using

Comment: nothing is dropping, I removed the addChild calls and made did the code you suggested in my createScene method but nothing is dropping.

Comment: @uswer1242 his code should work.When you `.addChild` inside of the function they are ALL going to drop. What you want to do is limit the `.addChild` (if you only want one to appear) or change the `.physicsBody?.pinned` if you want all to appear, but only one to drop. (See my answer)